# Is there a way to offline sign transaction hex with python?

Tags: python, cryptography, bitcoin, cryptocurrency

I have been searching for a function that takes raw transaction hex, private key and gives signed transaction hex as a result.

Comment: Note that hexadecimal is a representation or [tag:encoding] of a binary value (byte array) in text. "Raw hex" is therefore a contradiction of terms; you have raw binary or an encoded value representing that raw binary.

Comment: Your question should be here: bitcoin.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

Take a loot at pybitcointools, 
or have a look at [this article](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/46735/how-can-i-sign-transaction-hex-with-python-library) with the same toppic.

Hope this helps

Comment: Tried both already. No such function, in this article deserializeHex = bitcoin.deserialize(HEX) does not work. I get     val = from_byte_to_int(tx[pos[0]-1])

IndexError: index out of range

Answer (score 0):

You could do it with [BitcoinLib](https://github.com/1200wd/bitcoinlib). Import the raw transaction hex as Transaction object and then sign it with the private key.

```
private = "5c1a005d669f8521036f7c13138830f15b2d6a016facf9c6361362573e41a083"
raw_tx = ""  # Insert your raw tx in Hex format
t = Transaction.import_raw(raw_tx)
t.sign(private)
```

In this example the private key is in hex format, but bytes, key objects or WIF encoded strings are accepted as well.

Comment: How to do this in Tron?